# Hide "next" button on last item

Tags: php, jquery, hide

I have several divs that visitors can flip through with "previous" and "next" buttons. This is the code I wrote, which works fine:

```
$("#next").click(function(){
    $(".open").removeClass("open").fadeOut(200, function(){ // remove .open from current opened detail and fade out
        $(this).next(".outsourcing").addClass("open").fadeIn(400); // add .open to next detail and fade in
        if ($(".open").hasClass(".item<?php echo $outsourcing_count-1; ?>")) {
            $("#next").hide();
        }
    })
});
```

On the last item, I'd like to hide the "next" button. The last item isn't the last child in the containing div so I used PHP to tag it with a special class as you can see in the if statement above. But the if statement doesn't seem to be firing, any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: can u show your DOM structure (html code) ..

Comment: remove "." in .hasClass(".item<?php echo $outsourcing_count-1; ?>")

Comment: I gather from your comments you are only interested in PHP injection? Some feedback on the proposed *jQuery-only* alternatives would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove "." before item .. you don't have to give class Identifier when you are using hasClass

```
 if ($(".open").hasClass("item<?php echo $outsourcing_count-1; ?>")) {
            $("#next").hide();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a PHP injected value to test if it is the last item

```
if ($(".open").is(':last-child')) 
{
      // must be the last item
}
```

will do, or (if it is not the last child in that container) just check if there is a `next` item:

```
if (!$(".open").next(".outsourcing").length) 
{
      // must be the last item
}
```

You get the idea anyway. Just test for a specific DOM configuration, rather than messing about with panel numbering. You should not add dependencies if you don't need to.

Comment: *'The last item isn't the last child in the containing div'*